# Unobtrusive JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm tyring to learn JavaScript and i'm following some tutorials to learn it. In one is some simple code to teach about Unobtrusive JavaScript code. The code is simple, it needs to show a message when JavaScript is not active and when it is active it needs to show a plus sign that is clickable.

Below the html code:

```
 <body>
     <h1 id="title">18. Unobtrusive JavaScript</h1>
     <p id="main">

     </p>
     <p id="message">You should see this whether JavaScript is on or off.</p>
 </body>
```

And the JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#main').append("<img src='plus-8.png' alt='Click me to see the paragraph'    id='clickMe' />");

$('#clickMe').toggle(function() {
    $('#message').show('fast');
    $('#clickMe').attr('src', 'minus-8.png');

}, function() {
    $('#message').hide('slow');
    $('#clickMe').attr('src', 'plus-8.png');
});

$('#message').hide();

});
```

I only see the plus sign appear shortly and then it disappears. When I look at the source code the #main is there but has a display: none; and the #message also doesn't show. I can't get it to work and can't find out what I'm doing wrong. If somebody could help me, that would be nice.

Comment: Have you included the jQuery file properly in your project? Have you looked at the browser's console to see if any errors are reported?

Comment: A minor note... please add a `title` attribute to your image if you want that `alt` message to appear as a tooltip.  Only IE will display an `alt` attribute as a tooltip (as well)

Comment: It is not a problem with the image I think. Neither with the javascript. But something else is hiding that later. Maybe after loading some other js or css may hide it. I'd put there also something like `$('#clickMe').show();` after the `$('#main...` line

Comment: I mean you can always use a `<noscript>` tag.

Comment: I would suggest using the build in web console in Firefox or Chrome, it will allow you to test any of these simple functions and get immediate feedback.

Comment: The tutorial you're following is referencing an outdated jQuery feature. It's a good idea to check the publication date of any material like that. Anything more than a couple years old is suspect.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery `toggle` method can take three parameters, first is duration, second is easing (fast, slow) and third is function callback when animation is complete. You are passing two functions in `toggle` method, and hence when it completes showing your message, it then hides it in the second function call back.

Do something like this:

```
$('#clickMe').click(function() {
    $('#message').toggle('slow');

    // If image is plus, display minus
    // If image is minus, display plus
    if($('#clickMe').attr('src') === 'plus.svg') {
        $( '#clickMe').attr('src', 'minus.svg');
    } else {
        $( '#clickMe').attr('src', 'plus.svg');
    }
});
```

Comment: There was *another* `.toggle()` with an API like that used in the OP, but it was removed in 1.9.

Comment: Good to know @Pointy. Added image toggle code in above answer.

Comment: Did this work for you @user3524020? Please let us know.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for all the help. Your version does work for me. However it does not work exactly how it is supposed to work. When JavaScript is turned off it should always show the message. If it is turned on the plus image should be visible (no text should be visible) and when you press it, the message shows and a minus sign. I'm trying to fix it myself but i'm struggling a bit with it.

Comment: Oh well the solution was quite simple when my brain started working again... Forgot to put $('#message').hide(); in the code and now it works fine.